# Get coordinates from leaflet app embedded in webpage using python scraping

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, leaflet

I'm trying to download coordinates for points (ATMs in Czech Republic) from a webpage that is using embedded leaflet to visualize these points.

Here is the webpage: (it's in Czech Language)

http://www.kurzy.cz/banky/bankomaty/zatec-okres-louny/

I'm using python3

What I have done so far is used urllib to download the webpage and beautiful soup to somehow format it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = 'http://www.kurzy.cz/banky/bankomaty/zatec-okres-louny/'

raw_text = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
utf_text = raw_text.decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(utf_text)

scripts = soup.findAll("script")
scripts
```

What I want to get is hidden in 'point_list' variable - it contains coordinates and names of ATMs, but I am not successful in getting this variable.

```
...
point_list = ['', '/static/vizualizace/leaflet/img/icon/banky/zluta_bankomaty.svg', [50.3165463776, 13.535562001, '<b>Česká spořitelna</b><br />Husova 2908, Žatec<br />...
...
```

What I tried and wasn't working:

```
for link in soup.find_all("script"):
    if "point" in link:
        print(link)
```

It doesn't print anything.

There must be some important thing that I am missing and can't seem to find an answer to. I don't have a lot of experiences with scraping, I have only scraped some hyperlinks before, which was fairly straightforward.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the answer @vold, I was able to use it as a starter for what I needed as a result.

```
list_addresses = []
# first split by left bracket
for item in all_address.split('['):
    # then replace redundant characters
    replace_item1 = item.replace("<br /><b>GPS: </b>", ',')
    replace_item2 = replace_item1.replace("</b><br />", ",")
    replace_item = replace_item2.replace("'<b>", "")
    # and split an element (one ATM) by comma, creating a list of lists
    clean_item = replace_item.split(',')
    # strip whitespace
    strip_list = list(map(str.strip, clean_item))
    # creates list of lists
    list_addresses.append(strip_list)

# I don't need the first element  
Table = pd.DataFrame(list_addresses[1:])
Table
```

I think this is not a clean solution and would appreciate if there was something more elegant.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parsel](http://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) library and regex to get desired value from the page source like this:

```
import requests
from parsel import Selector


url = 'http://www.kurzy.cz/banky/bankomaty/zatec-okres-louny/'
r = requests.get(url)
sel = Selector(r.text)
all_address = sel.xpath('//script[contains(.,"point_list")]').re_first(r'point_list = \[(.*)\]\];')

for item in all_address.split(','):
    print(item)
```

But you can also get that value directly from the page with xpath expression: `//div[h2]/text()`